# Cannot execute any files from separate home partition

Tags: partitioning, mount, fstab

Recently migrated my home to a separate partition so I could have the same home on two distros.

As an effect I cannot execute any more binaries from my home directory which is something I do not want.

```
zython@eden:~$ lsblk 
NAME   MAJ:MIN RM   SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINT
sda      8:0    0 111,8G  0 disk 
├─sda4   8:4    0    10G  0 part 
├─sda2   8:2    0     1K  0 part 
├─sda5   8:5    0  11,7G  0 part [SWAP]
├─sda3   8:3    0    43G  0 part /home/zython
└─sda1   8:1    0  47,2G  0 part /
zython@eden:~$
```

This is the output of my lsblk.

Heres the output of my `/etc/fstab`:

```
zython@eden:~$ cat /etc/fstab 
# /etc/fstab: static file system information.
#
# Use 'blkid' to print the universally unique identifier for a
# device; this may be used with UUID= as a more robust way to name devices
# that works even if disks are added and removed. See fstab(5).
#
# <file system> <mount point>   <type>  <options>       <dump>  <pass>
# / was on /dev/sda1 during installation
UUID=327b357e-8ba4-40e5-99d3-dac54445471c /               ext4    errors=remount-ro 0       1
# swap was on /dev/sda5 during installation
UUID=f4ae0a1c-b1f3-4db1-8151-0f9e359b5f80 none            swap    sw              0       0
#home:

UUID=3d37837c-3136-45d7-bdd8-9d9dc5127568 /home/zython/ ext4 defaults,exec,user 0 0
```

I have seen other answers with NTFS partitions which is not the case here.

I only want to execute binaries again.

I have tried to put a exec flag there in the last line from the fstab and have restarted the machine since but that did not have any effect.

How should I proceed ?

Comment: I suspect it's because `user` implies `noexec` - and the latter option takes precedence. Since you're mounting it at boot-time via fstab, do you really need `user`?

Comment: i agree with steeldriver ... i have 3 different HD's connect in fstab .. they just use `defaults` without any other additions .. they seem to work fine... not sure if being `home` would have any difference .. my added drives are storage drives.. i am able to execute a script from those directories

Comment: ok, I changed the order of user and exec, and everything works now, much thanks !

Comment: Please add these as answers people.  OP, please mark correct answer as the accepted answer - writing it yourself if nobody else has when you read this.

Comment: @thomasrutter put an answer up ill accept

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As mentioned in steeldriver's comment, the problem is `user` in the mount options which implies `noexec` and is overriding the previous `exec`.  The `user` probably isn't needed and may be removable, but swapping the order of `user` and `exec` should work too.

Comment: It would've been nice to notify @steeldriver in order to let him get the credits.

Comment: @TomášPospíšek See [this meta question](https://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/17520/if-people-have-put-answers-as-comments-is-it-ok-for-me-to-copy-their-comment-to)

Comment: If steeldriver adds an answer then the OP could always change.

Comment: @J.Starnes & thomasrutter - it would have been nice, wouldn't it?

Comment: As you did not give credit to the one that actually answered the question, your answer smells like plagiarism.

Comment: @C.S.Cameron please see the exchange between myself and OP in the comments on the question: I'm more than happy for Steeldriver to add his comment as a question and get all credit but they haven't returned to do so and nor was OP willing to add it as an answer, but suggested that I do it so I did.  I also opened a discussion about this in meta.askubuntu.com at the time, which you can look and comment on.

Comment: @C.S.Cameron link here: https://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/17520/if-people-have-put-answers-as-comments-is-it-ok-for-me-to-copy-their-comment-to  Edit: I see you have commented there too, but have not expanded upon what should have been done instead.

Comment: You may use another person's words, ideas, or information, but to do so without acknowledgment is plagiarism. - bowdoin.edu  Comments are often removed, perhaps you should give steeldriver credit in your post.

Comment: I attempted to give an answer at your Meta question but the thread was closed as a duplicate. Have a look at how oldfred passes on information without taking credit for it.

Comment: The edit makes it look a lot better to me, upvote added.